# Javascript Objects in array selection

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

Hello stackoverflowians~!

It is I, a lonesome programmer who has encountered a problem during my trails.
You see the problem is with this piece of code.

```
for(var a = 0; a < bullets.length; a++) {
            for(var b = 0; b < pigs.length; b++) {
                if(bullets[a].y < 300) {
                    if(bullets[a].x > pigs[b].x && bullets[a].x < pigs[b].x + pigImage.width &&
                    bullets[a].y > pigs[b].y && bullets[a].y < pigs[b].y      + pigImage.height) {
                        pigExplode(pigs[b].x);
                        bullets.pop(a);
                        pigs.pop(b);
                        player.kills++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is as following.
I have 2 arrays with objects inside of them;
one array Bullets holding all bullet objects
and one array Pigs which hold all the pigs (Targets to shoot in my game)
(However, I do not encourage shooting pigs in any way)

Now what I'm trying to do is see if one of the bullets in the array hits one of the pigs in the array, i've added the pigs and bullets into the arrays like this:

```
bullets.push(new Bullet());
pigs.push(new Pig());
```

Where shit goes south is when I try to remove a certain object in this array, lets say I have 5 pigs.

that would be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.
If I were to shoot pig 2. 4 will die.
If I were to shoot pig 1. 4 will die.
If I were to shoot pig 4. 4 will die.

So no matter who I shoot it will always remove the last pig.
the error I get with this problem is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined
```

The line it indicates is this:

```
if(bullets[a].y < 300) {
```

this is in the double for loop where I check for any bullets hitting the pig.
the error however only pops up when I hit a pig that is not the last in the array.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on with my code?
I've been dealing with this for several days now and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with the code:

- You are using `pop` to remove items from the arrays, that will always remove the last item. That's why it's always killing the last pig.
- You are continuing the inner loop after a hit, so you will be checking hits for a bullet that's not in the array any more. If you were checking the last bullet, the variable `a` is now pointing beyond the last item in the array.

Use `splice` to remove items in an array, loop backwards through the bullets so that you can remove one without messing up the loop, and end the inner loop after a hit:

```
for (var a = bullets.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
  for (var b = 0; b < pigs.length; b++) {
    if (bullets[a].y < 300) {
      if (bullets[a].x > pigs[b].x && bullets[a].x < pigs[b].x + pigImage.width &&
          bullets[a].y > pigs[b].y && bullets[a].y < pigs[b].y      + pigImage.height) {
        pigExplode(pigs[b].x);
        bullets.splice(a, 1);
        pigs.splice(b, 1);
        player.kills++;
        break; // end the inner loop
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Changed this aswell, the game was working without the break; but now It's no longer spitting out an error, also this should speed up the game a slight bit ;D

+1 for optimization, Woo~!

Comment: And decrease a and b by one or you'll skip a pig and bullet.

Comment: @HMR: No, that will only make you recheck the previous bullet one more time. Skipping the rest of the pigs for a bullet that is removed is intentional (because it fixes a bug), and by doing the outer loop backwards you don't skip any bullets.

Comment: @Guffa You are right, I missed the counting down and because you break out of the pig loop after removing an item it doesn't matter there either.

Answer (score 0):

This will remore the pig from your pigs array if it's hit

```
if(bullets[a].x > pigs[b].x && a bunch of other stuff) {
  pigExplode(pigs[b].x);
  bullets.splice(a,1);//remove bullit at a
  pigs.splice(b,1);//remove pig at b
  player.kills++;//smell bacon, jummy
  //always forget this both bullits and pigs are one shorter
  // if you dont decrease the counters you'll skip one pig and bullit
  a--;
  b--;
}
```

.pop always removes the last item of the array.

Comment: That solved my problem! Thanks! :D
I thought .pop would accept my awesome parameters, but I've never been any more wrong ever before.

Thanks about 983 times.

Comment: @BobDesaunois You're welcome, good luck with the game. I've updated that you need to decrease the a and b counter or you'll skip a pig and bullet.